# What are the __gm_weak means in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

```
@interface Demo2ViewController () <GMGridViewDataSource, GMGridViewSortingDelegate, GMGridViewTransformationDelegate>
{
    __gm_weak GMGridView *_gmGridView1;
    __gm_weak GMGridView *_gmGridView2;

    __gm_weak UIButton *_buttonOptionsGrid1;
    __gm_weak UIButton *_buttonOptionsGrid2;

    UIPopoverController *_popOverController;
    UIViewController *_optionsController1;
    UIViewController *_optionsController2;
}
```

Trying out the GMGridview, and saw this __gm_weak GMGridView *_gmGridView1;.  Anyone know what __gm_weak means and when do you use __? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

those declarations are not common, they are defined in the GMGridView sources:

```
//
// ARC on iOS 4 and 5
//

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_5_0 && !defined (GM_DONT_USE_ARC_WEAK_FEATURE)
#define __gm_weak __weak
#else
#define __gm_weak __unsafe_unretained
#endif
```

as far as the double underscore usage, i'd advise against it. just consider it reserved for the implementation (e.g. toolchain) and use a normal identifier.